# How to encrypt a file using GnuPG in Linux?

Tags: gnupg

I'm trying to encrypt a file through `gpg` command with the passphrase. In the GUI application I have used the below command but it did not encrypt the file:

```
gpg --yes --passphrase [qwerty] -c -f &FILE 2>/dev/null
```

`&FILE` should take the files one by one and encrypt it, but it's not happening.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure where you found that command line, but it's not using parameters understood by GnuPG (there is no `-f` option). Also, the `&FILE` "variable" seems to be something special to your GUI application.

To encrypt a file, run

```
gpg --symmetric --passphrase [passphrase] [filename]
```

while you replace `[passphrase]` and `[filename]` with their actual values. Be aware that GnuPG writes to STDOUT per default, you might want to redirect the output into a file again.

```
gpg --symmetric --passphrase [passphrase] [filename] > [encrypted.pgp]
```